# Freshly installed Ubuntu boots into initramfs

Tags: system-installation, encryption, luks, initramfs

a few days ago I installed Linux Mint but had no luck getting wifi working so I switched over to Kubuntu. Everything was working fine and finally after some days of tweaking I had everything setup perfectly but one day I couldn't boot anymore since luks wouldn't accept my passphrase anymore.

So I tried to reinstall Kubuntu but ever since after every fresh reinstall it automatically boots into `initramfs`. I tried Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Linux Mint a few times but it still is always booting into `initramfs`.

Tried it without encryption, with wifi enabled and all the new updates and also without them but I just can't get it working. Also tried to format my HDD completely before installing but still no luck.

Anyone got any idea? I'd really appreciate it since I don't want to switch back to windows because of such a "small" problem.

Comment: Are you still looking for answers?